# I can't rename filename in VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, file-rename

I have a file called `Default2.aspx` that I'm trying rename to `Default.aspx`, but when I try to do it, the visual studio just rename back to `Default2.aspx` name.  Don't give even any error message. I don't know how to fix this. There's other file called `Default.aspx` anymore. I've already tried also restarting VS and even the pc. No luck.

I think that it is because VS believe still that there's the older `Default.aspx` file.. even if so, I still don't know where exactly look at to check out this.
also, couldn't VS give an error message? and is not this a VS bug?

I'm using VS 08 with ASP.NET appplication editing C# code

Comment: Does is still exist on disk? If you unload the webproject and then edit the project file is it still there? When you close your solution can you try to remove any *.suo and *.csproj.user files

Comment: No, I removed not from project but from disk too.

Comment: for edit: I will try to remove them.

Comment: this might be risky to try, but if you want to try it.  Open your proejct file (.csproj) in a editor like notepad you can see all the files VS thinks are part of your project.  See if it shows Default.aspx is still there.

Comment: Im also have this issue in VS 2013. How do you solved it?

Comment: This seems to happen when there are unsaved changes in the file, so a workaround is to ensure that all files are saved (shift-ctrl s by default) before  amending filename

Comment: This was happening to me while I had Show All Files enabled - any rename would just immediately stop. Rebooting didn't help, but turning off Show All Files did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you right clicking on the file and selecting rename?  Usually if this does not work for some reason it will give an error.

You can edit the file outside of the VS environment (this can be done easily by right clicking on the file, selecting "show containing folder" and changing the name there).  When you go back to VS, it should give you a message mentioning that the file name was changed outside the application and asking you to reload with changes.  However, depending on the type of file, this may break auto-generated statements that were based on the file's original name.

Comment: I'm doing exactly so, right clicking. It doesn't work and don't given an error. The VS just undo what I did. Rename outside of the VS environment is my last alternative because I will need to do a lot of others renames by hand.. yea I'm so lazy..

Comment: Happening to me too, Visual Studio 2017

Comment: This happened to me. It turns out I was debugging the project, and I guess you cannot rename files while debugging. ‍♂️

Comment: It happens to me on new update of vs. I'm not debugging. Restart won't fix it. Maybe is some Marketplace addon that cause this but can't figure it out. no error message.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the filename in your file explorer, then in visual studio remove the files with the old name and right click Add --> Existing item... add the file with the new name.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2951059/garrison) mentioned in his comment, you can't rename/delete files while you're debugging.